# On window refresh `HostListner` - not works as expected

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a parent, and child component, in parent component i am passing data to child, when the user in child as well he refresh the page, no data will be there as naturally.

from the parent ( because no.of childrens ) - I am trying to deduct the refresh and redirecting the page to parent. I am tried with following approach, but not works. I seen it in a answer from stackoverflow.

her is the code : I am using **Angular 8**

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload') goToPage() {
        console.log('window refreshed');
    }
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-detect-refresh-page-and-redirect-to-another-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only ask the user that the application will reload, and nothing else can be done.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-detect-refresh-page-and-redirect-to-anoth-tmuqze?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: try to reload or close tab, you will see prompt window